# c# .NET Core SignalR exception when client calls a function (not always happens)

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have the following Server `SignalR` Hub:

```
 public class AlertHub : Hub
    {
        static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            return Clients.All.SendAsync("BroadcastMessage", user, message);
        }

        public Task SendMessageToUser(string userUid, string user, string message, string totalMessages)
        {
            var clientId = _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == userUid).Key;
            return Clients.Client(clientId).SendAsync("BroadcastMessage", user, message, totalMessages);
        }

        public static void ClearState()
        {
            _users.Clear();
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            _users.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, Context.ConnectionId);

            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            string userUid;
            _users.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId, out userUid);

            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        public void SetUserUid(string userUid)
        {
            _users[Context.ConnectionId] = userUid;
        }
    }
```

On my client just before the `await _signalRConnection.StartAsync();` I set the `userUid` to my `_users` dictionary:

```
//Send user name for this client, so we won't need to send it with every message
                await _signalRConnection.InvokeAsync("SetUserUid", this.State.UserUID);
```

And that works perfect, no exception.

Then on my client when I try to send a message I do the following: (this normally works, the exception is intermitent)

```
await _signalRConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessageToUser", model.UserUid.ToString().ToLower(), this.State.UserName, $"{model.UserName} has sent you a message.", countMessagesString);
```

This normally works but sometimes it started to crash showing in the server the following error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher.? [?] - MESSAGE: Failed to invoke hub method 'SendMessageToUser'.
 System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionId')
```

That for is that when trying to get the clientId it returns null here:

```
 var clientId = _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == userUid).Key; <-- HERE
return Clients.Client(clientId).SendAsync("BroadcastMessage", user, message, totalMessages);
```

So I don't know why the `_users` dictionary won't have the key sometimes. This is pretty strange.

Any clue on how to dig around or to solve it?

** UPDATE **

This is what I did:

```
  public class AlertHubDictionary
    {
        static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _users;

        public AlertHubDictionary()
        {
            _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> UsersDictionary { get { return _users; } }

        public void ClearUsersDictionary()
        {
            _users.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Then this class registered as Singleton DI:

```
   services.AddSingleton<AlertHubDictionary>();
```

And finally do the replacements on the Hub class:

```
public class AlertHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AlertHub> _logger;
        private AlertHubDictionary _hubDictionary;
        static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public AlertHub(ILogger<AlertHub> logger, AlertHubDictionary hubDictionary)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _hubDictionary = hubDictionary;
        }
        public Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            //Clients.Client("").SendAsync("BroadcastMessage", user, message);
            return Clients.All.SendAsync("BroadcastMessage", user, message);
        }

        public Task SendMessageToUser(string userUid, string user, string message, string totalMessages)
        {
            //var clientId = _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == userUid).Key;
            var clientId = _hubDictionary.UsersDictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == userUid).Key;

            using (var scope = _logger.BeginScope("SCOPED_VALUE"))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Send message to userUid {userUid} - {user} with clientId {clientId}.");

            }


            if (clientId == null)
            {
                // the user is not connected
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
            else
            {

                return Clients.Client(clientId).SendAsync("BroadcastMessage", user, message, totalMessages);
            }
        }

        public void ClearState()
        {
            _hubDictionary.ClearUsersDictionary();
            //_users.Clear();

            using (var scope = _logger.BeginScope("SCOPED_VALUE"))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("_users cleared");

            }

        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            _hubDictionary.UsersDictionary.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, Context.ConnectionId);
            //_users.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, Context.ConnectionId);

            using (var scope = _logger.BeginScope("SCOPED_VALUE"))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"ConnectionId {Context.ConnectionId} connected.");

            }

            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            string userUid;
            _hubDictionary.UsersDictionary.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId, out userUid);

            using (var scope = _logger.BeginScope("SCOPED_VALUE"))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"UserUid {userUid} disconnected.");

            }


            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        public void SetUserUid(string userUid)
        {
            _hubDictionary.UsersDictionary[Context.ConnectionId] = userUid;

            using (var scope = _logger.BeginScope("SCOPED_VALUE"))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Connection {Context.ConnectionId} linked to userUid {userUid}");

            }

            //ClientNameChanged?.Invoke(Context.ConnectionId, userName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put logging into file. Log from methods where the `_users` is added/emptied. You are probably losing connection from time to time = that's why it is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way that you're capturing the user IDs, it looks like you are trying to treat the SignalR hub as a singleton. Per Microsoft's documentation, the hub is a transient class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-and-use-hubs

> Hubs are transient:
>
> Don't store state in a property on the hub class. Every hub method
> call is executed on a new hub instance.

As such, if you want to keep a shared instance of your registered user IDs, you should probably manage that as a separate class registered as a singleton and injected into your hub class so that the state can be maintained independently of the hub.

Comment: Awesome. Yes that makes totally sense. Any link where I can look on how to implement it?

Comment: @VAAA - You could do it as simply as moving that Dictionary into its own class, registering it at startup `service.AddSingleton<YourUserCacheClass>()`, and then injecting it into the hub's constructor using constructor injection as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#overview-of-dependency-injection

Comment: There's a very similar standalone class example here from Microsoft, albeit marked internal whereas you'd be fine with public: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientMappingRegistry.cs

Comment: Appreciate so much, I will give it a try

Comment: Just updated with the change I did, Im going to try.